# Meaning and usage of: [〜か]　〜か　にもよりません

Tags: grammar

There seems to be a relatively rarely used grammatical pattern consisting of either a single か clause, or a AかBか, or else Aかどうか, followed by にもよりません。

Based on the scanty examples of this that can be found online, it seems to mean something like "irrespective of".  Aかにもよりません seems to mean that it isn't a problem if the question posed by A doesn't have an affirmative answer: "regardless of whether A". Similarly, AかBかにもよりません seems to mean "regardless of whether A or B".

But really, what is the meaning? Plus other considerations like usage restrictions and whatnot.

Comment: Can you provide examples and links? This pattern didn't show up in a few quick corpora searches I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just "AかBかによりません" except that も meaning "also/either" or "even" is added. 依る【よる】 is an intransitive verb that means "to rely/depend on". You can learn its basic usage [here](https://nihononthego.tumblr.com/post/131692018892/grammar-depends-ondiffers-depending-on).

AかBかによらない works predicatively or adjectivally, AかBかによらず works adverbially.

- AかBかによりません。
  (It) does not depend on whether it's A or B.
- AかBかに**も**よりません。
  (It) does not depend on whether it's A or B, **either**.
  (It) does not **even** depend on whether it's A or B.
- AかBかによらず
  regardless of whether it's A or B
- Aかどうかによらず
  regardless of whether or not it's A